# Understanding SSL Cipher suite in Apache

Tags: apache, cipher-selection, ciphers

On reading the documentation [Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslciphersuite). A cipher suite example has been given :

```
RC4-SHA:AES128-SHA:HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5
```

I have understood the explanation given by them. My question is whether it decides the order of the cipher suite ?

Meaning : RC4-SHA ciphers has been given top priority? Or a cipher which is obtained by matching all the ciphers given ?

Can someone clearly explain what it means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the order of Apache's `SSLCipherSuite` indicates the preferred order.  To quote the link you've provided (emphasis mine),

> Now where this becomes interesting is that these can be put together
>   to **specify the order** and ciphers you wish to use

During the TLS handshake, the client presents its cipher suite, and then the server will select the appropriate cipher to use, as dictated by the `SSLHonorCipherOrder`.  If `off` (the default), then the server will consider each cipher in *Server suite order* and use the first cipher which is also present in the Client suite.  If `on`, then the server will consider each cipher in the *Client suite order* and use the first cipher which is also present in the Server suite.  (Thanks to @steffen-ullrich for correcting me on that detail).

Because `SSLCipherSuite` accepts aliases that map to more than one cipher (e.g., "`HIGH`", "`MEDIUM`", "`!MD5`") you can see the actual server cipher order that results from the `SSLCipherSuite` string using `openssl ciphers`:

```
$ openssl ciphers 'RC4-SHA:AES128-SHA:HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5'
RC4-SHA:AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:SRP-DSS-AES-256-CBC-SHA:SRP-RSA-AES-256-CBC-SHA:SRP-AES-256-CBC-SHA:DH-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA256:DH-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DH-DSS-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DH-RSA-AES256-SHA:DH-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA:DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA256-SHA:DH-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA:DH-DSS-CAMELLIA256-SHA:ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:AES256-SHA:CAMELLIA256-SHA:PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:SRP-DSS-AES-128-CBC-SHA:SRP-RSA-AES-128-CBC-SHA:SRP-AES-128-CBC-SHA:DH-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DH-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DH-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA:DH-RSA-AES128-SHA:DH-DSS-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA:DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA128-SHA:DH-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA:DH-DSS-CAMELLIA128-SHA:ECDH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:CAMELLIA128-SHA:PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA:DHE-RSA-SEED-SHA:DHE-DSS-SEED-SHA:DH-RSA-SEED-SHA:DH-DSS-SEED-SHA:SEED-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:ECDH-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDH-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:PSK-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:SRP-DSS-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA:SRP-RSA-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA:SRP-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:DH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:DH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDH-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:PSK-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA
```

Comment: *"the server goes through its list of ciphers in order until it finds a cipher that's common to both suites"* - this is only true with `SSLHonorCipherOrder Directive` set to `off` (which is the default). If `on` it will instead go through all the ciphers the client offers in the order given by the client and choose the first one which is also  supported by the server.

Comment: Better to say: when `SSLHonorCipherOrder` is `On`:  server goes through its list of ciphers to check if there is a match with in cipher list. But it is stated that: `When choosing a cipher during an SSLv3 or TLSv1 handshake, normally the client's preference is used. If this directive is enabled, the server's preference will be used instead` in the [apache doc](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#SSLHonorCipherOrder)
which means it is effecting in `SSLv3` or `TLSv1` only.